# plane fitting with normalized coefficients

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares

I am Trying to fit 3d-points to a plane in 2.5d/3d using **scipy.optimize.leastsq**.

I am trying to minimize the function: a*x + b*y + c - z

When I add noise to the planes I'm generating, I am starting to get different results for (a,b,c), while the linear relationship between a and b remains correct.

**My question:** Is there a way to constrain a normalization of the fitting parameters?

I can normalize after the optimization and run another search for the last parameter but it feels inefficient and it causes big variations to parameter c, any recommendations?

Thanks!

#### Here are some different results I got for the same plane:

```
[ 12.88343415     6.7993803   4001.717 ] 

[ 14.52913549     7.44262692  3201.1523]

[ 4.37394650e+00   2.20546734e+00   9.56e+03]

[ 24.32259278    12.32581015 -2748.026]
```

#### After normalizing by sqrt(a**2 +b**2 +1):

```
[-0.97401694  0.20292819 -6.16468053] 
[-0.97527745  0.1976869  -2.46058884] 
[-0.97573799  0.19342358  5.42282738] 
[ -0.97894621   0.17992336  13.52561491] 
[ -0.97821728   0.17834579  24.5345626 ]
```

#### code:

```
def least_squares(neighborhood,p0):
    """
    computes the least mean squares solution for points in neighborhood.
    p0 is the initial guess for (a,b,c)
    returns a,b,c for the local minima found.
    """
    if neighborhood.shape[0]<5:
        return None
    sol = leastsq(residuals, p0, args=(None, neighborhood.T))[0]
    return sol

def f_min(X, p):
    """
    plane function to minimize.
    """
    ab = p[0:2]
    distance = (ab*X[:2].T).sum(axis=1) + p[2] - X[2]
    return distance

def residuals(params, signal, X):
    """
    residuals for least mean squares
    """
    return f_min(X, params)



p0 = np.random.uniform(-50, 50, size=(3,1))
sol = least_squares(neighborhood,p0)
```

Comment: What does 'constraing normalization of the fitting parameters' mean? Do you want to apply constraints to the possible values, add a regularization term, etc.? What's the goal of doing this? Also, what does 'normalizing by sqrt(a2 + b2 + 1)' mean?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.
The output I desire is the a,b,c,d for the plane equation:
ax+by+cz+d=0 
But I want [a,b,c], the normal vector, to be normalized.

The way I am currently doing is:
- I use 3 parameters where c=-1.
- divide a,b,d in sqrt(a^2+b^2+c^2).

As a result I get a normalized [a,b,c] but this process is not ideal for my purpose- 
When Z is big, d is proportionally big and introduces big errors even after the normalization, see the second block of output above.

Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:
Given N X,Y,Z values  you want to find a,b,c,d to minimise

```
Q = Sum{ i | square( (a,b,c)*(X[i], Y[i], Z[i])' - d)}
```

whatever value you choose for (a,b,c) the value of d that minimises this will be

```
d = Sum{ i | (a,b,c)*(X[i], Y[i], Z[i])' }/N
  = (a,b,c)*(Xbar,Ybar,Zvar)
```

where Xbar is the average of the X etc.

Plugging this into the expression for Q, we get

```
Q = Sum{ i | square( (a,b,c)*(x[i], y[i], x[i])')} 
  = (a,b,c)*Sum{ i | (x[i], y[i], x[i])' * (x[i], y[i], x[i])}*(a,b,c)'
  = (a,b,c)*M*(a,b,c)'
```

where x[i] = X[i]-xbar, y[i]=Y[i]-ybar etc and

```
M = Sum{ i | (x[i], y[i], x[i])' * (x[i], y[i], x[i])}
```

The minimum of q for normalised (a,b,c) will be the smallest eigenvector of M and then (a,b,c) will be an eigenvector for that eigenvalue.

So the procedure is:

a/ compute the means xbar,ybar,zbar of the coordinates and subtract these from x[],y[],z[]

b/ form the matrix M and diagonalise it

c/ the eigenvector for the lowest eigenvalue of M gives you (a,b,c)

d/ compute d via

```
d = (a,b,c)*(xbar,ybar,zbar)'
```

Comment: Thanks! it works great. Do you know if there are fundamental difference between this approach to the least squares?

A followup question - 
For a given plance, I got many normal vectors pointing the opposite directions, (vi = -1*vj). I solved it by multiplying abcd in -1 if sum(abc)<0.
Would you do it differently?